# Querying NoSQL databases

Tags: linq, nosql

I haven't been able to find a lot of nice information on the topic so I thought that I would ask here.  I have no real experience working with NoSQL databases, but from what I've read NoSQL databases sort of seem like giant JavaScript objects.  LINQ to JSON exists, LINQ can be used for querying any collection.  Why can't LINQ become the language for querying NoSQL databases?

Comment: If you're going to downvote a topic on which I have in the question described my nascence, please explain why.  This does nothing to prevent what you might think are bad questions in the future.

Comment: I haven't down voted you but I thought I would weigh in here ... It's not clear what you're asking, the issue with stack overflow and this kind of question is that you need to be a bit more specific about exactly what you are questioning, in the answer below the answerer talks about multiple database technologies which each have their own ways of working so it's hard to be specific.

Answer (score 6):

LINQ *can* be used for querying several popular NoSQL databases (at least those with .NET clients).

For example:

- [Using LINQ to Query RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/using-linq-to-query-ravendb?version=2.5)
- [C# LINQ Driver for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/)
- [Linq2Couchbase](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Linq2Couchbase)

Comment: thank you.  Do you have any experience using these clients?  As intuitive as LINQ is, it (or a close cousin) seems to me that it'd be a prime candidate for the de facto standard querying language.